# Referencing 1 column from 1 model to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a requirement to show 1 column from different model on MVC. Im a first timer in mvc so im not really familiar with lambda convention...

So far I have this classes

article.cs

```
 public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int bl_id { get; set; }
    [Column("bl_title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Column("bl_img")]
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [Column("bl_summ")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    [Column("bl_content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [Column("bl_author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode =true, DataFormatString ="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Column("bl_dtecrt")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

the next class is the comments:

comments.cs

```
 public class Comments

{
    [Key]
    public int ic_id { get; set; }
    public int ic_blid { get; set; }
    public string ic_comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime ic_crtdte { get; set; }
    public string ic_pcname { get; set; }

}
```

What I need is to have relate the Title Column from the Articles.cs models to the set of Comments... if it were on sql i could do a select query in this manner: select article.title, comments.ic_comment from articles, comments where articles.bl_id = comments.ic_blid

So far, the solution i tried is create a join in the controller then throw it to the view...

articlescontroller.cs

```
 public ActionResult Comments()
    {
        var comm = from c in db.Comments
                   join a in db.Articles
                   on c.ic_blid equals a.bl_id
                   select c;
        return View("Comments", comm.ToList());
    }
```

EDIT: View

Comments.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.Comments>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Comments";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ic_comment)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ic_crtdte)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ic_pcname)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Article.Title)
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ic_comment)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ic_crtdte)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ic_pcname)
    </td>
         <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ic_id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ic_id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ic_id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

but my view is not catering the columns from the articles.

So my question is, how can I incorporate 1 or more columns from my Articles Model to my Comments Models then show them in the view? The reason behind this module is to maintain the comments done in the articles posted.

I tried putting this in the comments model:

```
public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
```

but i dont know how to use.

I hope you can help me...

Comment: Can you post code from your View as well?

Comment: @Charanraj added view markup

Comment: As far as I understand you have an Article which can have zero or more comments (a list of comments). So in order get details about the comment you will have to include Comments when you query your DB. The result would contain a list of Article. Each article will have a list of comments.When you try to display Article name, you need to display comments along with it. Let me know if my understanding about this question is correct.

Comment: Exactly! But in my requirement, I just need the title of the Article where the end user made a comment. This module is for deleting unnecessary comments from the made article. So the list should, in every Article titles, the corresponding comments made in it will also show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in below 2 ways.                                                                                         Create a Class which contains Comments and Title. Construct the object from this select result and pass it to Model.
                                                                                     Or have a Navigation property for comments in Article class. And modify LINQ-SQL as below.

- Artice class

  ```
  public class Article
  {
  [Key]
  public int bl_id { get; set; }
  [Column("bl_title")]
  public string Title { get; set; }
  [Column("bl_img")]
  public string Image { get; set; }
  [Column("bl_summ")]
  public string Summary { get; set; }
  [AllowHtml]
  [Column("bl_content")]
  public string Content { get; set; }
  [Column("bl_author")]
  public string Author { get; set; }
  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
  [Column("bl_dtecrt")]
  public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
  ```

  }

Query
             var comments1 = from c in comments
             join a in articles
             on c.ic_blid equals a.bl_id
             select a;

View as below

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Article>

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Comments";    
}

<h2>Comments</h2>

<p>
  @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>

    <th>Title</th>
    <th>ic_comment</th>
    <th>ic_blid</th>
    <th>ic_crtdte</th>
    <th>ic_pcname</th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item1 in Model)
{
foreach (var item in item1.Comments)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ic_comment)
        </td>       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ic_blid)
        </td>       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ic_crtdte)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ic_pcname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ic_id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ic_id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ic_id })
        </td>

    </tr>
 }
}

</table>
```

Comment: I dont have to do changes in my comments class? like Public Virtual ICollection<Article> Articles?

Comment: Yes ( at present no need) in second approach as you are getting article details and in viewing comments along with article title.

Comment: Hi! I tried your answer but now it throws System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. 

The inner exceptions says:
SqlException: Invalid column name 'Article_bl_id'.
Invalid column name 'Article_bl_id'.
Invalid column name 'Article_bl_id'.

i dont see where the error is coming :(

Comment: so this is my actionresult

`var comm = from c in db.Comments
                       join a in db.Articles
                       on c.ic_blid equals a.bl_id
                       select a;
            return View("Comments", comm.ToList());`
And i added this in my articles Column `public virtual ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }` 

now it throwing an exception: `SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.CommentsArticle'.`

Comment: Did you use same view after these two changes, tested my code and worked fine at my end. Where are you referencing CommentsArticle

Comment: how can i do a navigation with these tables. im a beginner in mvc that's why  i have designed my tables first before doing the classes... should create a foreign key connection to my classes/tables?

Comment: Hi - Did you still facing the issue? Not getting complete idea where you got stuck?

Comment: hmm actually, i got the result that i need, but the problem now is it's repeating the results at least 3 times. for example: in the database there 3 articles where the end-user commented. The result is it will show the article titles and the comments in it at least three times. i just dont know how to suppress the repeating values/row

Comment: You use LINQ distinct function. Please refer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8c19e8/different-ways-to-get-distinct-values-from-a-listt-using/

Comment: i tried this:return View("Intranet_Comments", comm.Distinct().ToList());  but it throws error: 

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`3[System.String,System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication3.Models.Article]'. 

been stuck with it for the past 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to correct your Article class.
Since a Article can have many comments you need a property describing the same

(Please note the code is not tested)

```
public class Article{
    ...
    public List<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Now the place where you are trying to retrieve the data, include comments as well. Something like this:

```
public ActionResult Comments()
{
    var comm = db.Article.Include(x=>x.Comments).ToList(); 
    // This will get All article and include comments if any for each article.
    return View("Comments", comm.ToList());
}
```

In your view you would have to iterate Comment for individual Article

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Comments";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@foreach (var item in Model) {
@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Article.Title)
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments.ic_comment)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments.ic_crtdte)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments.ic_pcname)
    </td>
    <td

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ic_id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ic_id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ic_id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: If i add a list on my Article class, should i add a column of comments on my articles table? If that so, then my other actions pertaining the Article module will be affected, am i right?

Comment: Since Article has one or many comment, you should be having a column for article in your comment table. I recommend that you go through building a basic CRUD application. You can refer to the book 
Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 by Apress publication to get a good understanding of the framework

Answer (score 0):

Need to declare the Model for the View as dynamic. Please see 
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-data-in-Single-View-from-Multiple-Tables-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx
if it helps.

Also modify as below

```
              var comm = from c in db.Comments
               join a in db.Articles
               on c.ic_blid equals a.bl_id
               select new {c,a.title};
```

Comment: due to my beginner level on MVC i dont know if the link you gave me will work on EF approach but i'll give it a try. Also, the modification you gave me red line saying: implicitly-typed variables cannot have multiple declarators.

Comment: Corrected it. Please check

Comment: how would you return it to view? I mean, how would you assign this to your view?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Jja is the accepted answer but since i had a trouble with navigation property...

As per this stackoverflow link: [The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314967/entity-framework-net-the-name-value-should-be-a-valid-navigation-property-nam/32315140%20%22The%20Name%20value%20should%20be%20a%20valid%20navigation%20property%20name.%E2%80%9D)

My problem when using ForeignKey, the virtual table you're connecting to must have the same name on the [ForeignKey("")] tag. Before, my Comments class was defined as this:

```
 [Table("Intranet_Comments")]
public class Intranet_Comments

{
    [Key]
    public int ic_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Intranet_Article")]
    public int ic_blid { get; set; }
    public string ic_comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime ic_crtdte { get; set; }
    public string ic_pcname { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }       

}
```

And it throws navigation error... i re-wrote this class into:

[Table("Intranet_Comments")]
    public class Intranet_Comments

```
{
    [Key]
    public int ic_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Article")]
    public int ic_blid { get; set; }
    public string ic_comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime ic_crtdte { get; set; }
    public string ic_pcname { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }       

}
```

The foreign key property name must be the same name as the virtual property set..

i hope this helps!